# Google Cloud Build Quota exceeded (Build and Operation Get requests)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

Time to time my CI gets the error:

> Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Build and Operation Get requests' and
> limit 'Build and Operation Get requests per minute' of service
> 'cloudbuild.googleapis.com' for consumer

And I see that it's really exeeded.

[image]

But it's not posible to set the qouta more than 60.

[image]

Is there any way to get it more and pay for that?

Answer (score 3):

Google's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/build/quotas) says that, if you're unable to increase the quota using Cloud Console to contact Cloud Support.

It's curious that your quota rate is 60/minute. For a newly-created project, the quota rate I see is 300/minute.

An interim solution is to retry failed build operations after one minute. From your graph, you're only infrequently exceeding the rate.

Comment: Is it possible to ask Cloud Support for increasing the quota without having Technical Support offering?